# Which is the Stack Overflow question with the most number of answers?

Tags: discussion

I found this Stack Overflow question, *[What's your favorite “programmer” cartoon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556)*, which got ***135*** answers!

Is this the most answered question? Or something else?

Comment: It actually has 303 answers. A lot of them are just deleted.

Comment: There is data.stackexchange.com query http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/418517/question-with-most-answers. It gives https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered with 549 answers (may be deleted stuff included) so 518 existing answers

Comment: @animuson who.. 303 :O so is that the one with more answers?

Comment: You can use [search to find those which have more than 400 answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A400)

Comment: @animuson Why huge numbers of answers are deleted in that question?

Comment: @Iam It's an old question from before we had Imgur that was mostly filled with images. A ton of the links died.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Counting deleted answers, here are the top 10:

1. **518** [What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/184618)
2. **459** [What is your best programmer joke?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/234075)
3. **407** [What's your most controversial programming opinion?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/406760)
4. **320** [Strangest language feature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1995113)
5. **316** [What non-programming books should programmers read?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38210)
6. **296** [Hidden Features of C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9033)
7. **214** [What is the single most influential book every programmer should read?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1711)
8. **195** [Long-held, incorrect programming assumptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/888224)
9. **191** [Hidden features of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/101268)
10. **182** [What are five things you hate about your favorite language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/282329)

Note that all of these are either closed or locked. Lots and lots of answers are a bad sign.

Answer (score 3):

The query for most answers was given in the comments: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/418517/question-with-most-answers

And here is a query for open questions only, which excludes closed and locked posts: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1012309/open-question-with-most-answers